# Change mysql password in Docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

How could I change root password in docker container since the container stop automatically once I stop the mysql service.

Should I stop the mysql container and deploy a new one?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You could change it from a running container, using a [`docker exec` session](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/), as described in "[Connecting to MySQL Server from within the Container](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker#connecting-to-mysql-server-from-within-the-container)"

> Once the server is ready, you can run the mysql client within the MySQL Server container you just started and connect it to the MySQL Server.
> Use the `docker exec -it` command to start a `mysql` client inside the Docker container you have started, like this:
>
> ```
> docker exec -it mysql1 mysql -uroot -p
> ```
>
> When asked, enter the generated root password (see the instructions above on how to find it). Because the `MYSQL_ONETIME_PASSWORD` option is true by default, after you started the server container with the sample command above and connected a mysql client to the server, you must reset the server root password by issuing this statement for MySQL 5.7 and above :
>
> ```
> mysql> update user set authentication_string=password('new_password') where user='root';
> ```

or alternatively run,

> ```
> mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root' = PASSWORD('new_password');
> ```

For MySQL 5.7 and older versions, run,

> ```
> mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';
> ```
>
> Substitute `newpassword` with the password of your choice. Once the password is reset, the server is ready for use.

Note that the above command will only change the password for 'root' connecting from 'localhost' host. You can verify this by using the command:

> ```
> select * from mysql.user;
> ```

To alter the password for 'root' from all hosts, use:

> ```
> ALTER USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';
> ```

Then, as described in "[`hub.docker.com/mysql`](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)", dont forget [docker secrets](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/):

> As an alternative to passing sensitive information via environment variables, `_FILE` may be appended to the previously listed environment variables, causing the initialization script to load the values for those variables from files present in the container.
> In particular, this can be used to load passwords from Docker secrets stored in `/run/secrets/<secret_name>` files.
> For example:
>
> ```
> $ docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/mysql-root -d mysql:tag
> ```

---

[xeruf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6723250/xeruf) points out in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249912/change-mysql-password-in-docker-container/48249930#comment126233716_48249930) to "[`MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` is set but getting "`Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"` in docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59839180/6309)", adding:

> If you mount a volume, make sure to clear it when changing the `USER/PASSWORD`!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. Docker should be a good choice for non-specialised maintainers! Cheers~

Comment: the `ALTER USER` command did not work for me, running mysql 5.6.  I receive an `ERROR 1064 (42000): you have an error... near 'identified by .. at line 1`

Comment: @Logikos did you type the `mysql>`? Because it is a prompt which is not part of the command.

Comment: @VonC no I did not, here is a screenshot: https://pasteboard.co/Hqmyrp5.png

Comment: @Logikos mysql 5.6?... I am afraid that syntax is only valid in mySQL 5.7(!) and above: https://mysqlserverteam.com/improved-alter-user-syntax-support-in-5-7/#crayon-5b26cb8e7c00b541395201

Comment: thanks @VonC I have not really done anything with this container yet, I'm just going to replace it.

Comment: Using the docker MySQL client ... brilliant! Thanks for the tip!  And I wasted time installing a MySQL client on the host ... ???

Comment: To solve the Logikos issue you should specify the full info for the user >>'root'@'localhost' <<

Comment: what if I forget the password and I want to change a new password?

Comment: @lily That I don't know: that would be a good separate question to ask.

Comment: @lily, you can try to exec into the container and issue command `$ printenv`. If you're lucky, the container might have it's password in the env variables

Comment: If you mount a volume, make sure to clear it when changing the USER/PASSWORD! stackoverflow.com/a/59839180/6723250

Comment: @xeruf Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 4):

First go to docker container bash using

`docker exec -it containerId bash`

**Then**

- To Set the new mysql password

  `mysqladmin -u root -p'oldpassword' password 'newpassword'`
- To set the password empty use

  `mysqladmin -u root -p'oldpassword' password ''`

**Make sure there is no space between** `-p` **and** `oldpassword`

Answer (score 4):

In case you forgot the old password, you can reset it following a few steps. I wrote a tutorial on how to do it (you can show you support by giving a few claps): https://medium.com/@marinbinzari/reset-root-mysql-password-in-docker-d961c71285e4

**TLDR**: create a `mysql-init.sql` file with the queries to reset the password:

```
USE mysql;
UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Mount the file in the `/tmp` folder, run the container (not execute so MySQLD is not started) and then start the mysqld with the init script.

```
mysqld_safe --init-file=/tmp/mysql-init.sql &
```

Try to connect, exit the docker container and start using the new password

Oh, and never forget you password again

Comment: I basically used this method but instead of the init file I used `mysql_safe --skip-grant-tables` inside the running container. You can then `mysql -uroot` without a password and try different methods to directly change the password.

Comment: Does this method overwrite existing DB container?

Answer (score 1):

To reset the root Password in MYQL 8.0 unfortunatley the upcoming tipp from Martin Binzari does not work anymore completly. But you can do following:
(According his manual and [How to reset the root password in MySQL 8.0.11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691977/how-to-reset-the-root-password-in-mysql-8-0-11))

1. Create a `mysql-init.sql`

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=null WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

2. Mount it to /tmp folder.
3. Stop the container with `docker-compose stop mysql`
4. Run `docker-compose run mysql bash`
5. Inside run command `mysqld_safe --init-file=/tmp/mysql-init.sql &`
6. Wait 10s, press enter and run `mysql -uroot`
7. Then you could run command `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'yourpasswd';`
8. Finally you could exit and login shoud work with new root password.

Comment: mysqld_safe: command not found

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions proposed here didn't work for me, but I found [this blog post by Wolfgang Gassler](https://wolfgang.gassler.org/reset-password-mariadb-mysql-docker/) helpful, especially for those using `docker compose`.

Basically, the steps are:

1. add `command: --skip-grant-tables` to your MySQL (or MariaDB) service in your `docker-compose.yml`.
2. restart the service (i.e. `docker compose up -d <db>` where `<db>` is then name of your docker compose service).
3. `docker compose exec -it <db> bash` to get a bash prompt in the service's container.
4. `mysql -uroot` from the command line inside the container to get a MYSQL prompt, then enter the following 3 commands, replacing `newpassword` with your new password (obviously):

```sql
USE mysql;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
ALTER USER 'root'@'%'  IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';`
```

5. remove the `command: --skip-grant-tables` from your `docker-compose.yml`
6. restart the service again

Hope this helps someone else.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the password at the time of running the container using the -e option, which sets the environment variable `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`

```
docker run -d \
  --name=mysql5.7 \
  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456 \
  -p 3306:3306 mysql/mysql-server:latest
```