# How to reset the root password in MySQL 8.0.11?

Tags: mysql, passwords, root

I have actually lost my root password and I need to change it.  I follow these steps :

1. Stop the MySQL server process.
2. Start the MySQL (mysqld) server/daemon process with the `--skip-grant-tables` option so that it will not prompt for a password.
3. Connect to the MySQL server as the root user.

That can be found on these website : https://www.howtoforge.com/setting-changing-resetting-mysql-root-passwords#recover-mysql-root-password

```
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD("TOOR");
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit
```

First error, so I tried :

```
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("TOOR") where User='root';
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit
```

Always the same error said :

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '("TOO
R") WHERE User='root'' at line 1
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: It looks like it has a problem with the keyword `TOOR`, but I cannot see where you have used that. Would you show us the actual SQL you are running?

Comment: What is the first error?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

As [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) says:

> “This function was removed in MySQL 8.0.11”

1. If you in `skip-grant-tables` mode
   in `mysqld_safe`:

   ```
   UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=null WHERE User='root';
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   exit;
   ```

   And then, in the terminal:

   ```
   mysql -u root
   ```

   And then in MySQL:

   ```sql
   ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'yourpasswd';
   ```
2. Not in `skip-grant-tables` mode just in MySQL:

   ```sql
   ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'yourpasswd';
   ```

Comment: For in SKIP-GRANT-TABLES mode - sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables . Works for 8.0.1

Comment: I got `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mysql.role_edges' doesn't exist` so I had to do a `mysql_upgrade -u root` after I set the root password to null for this to work.

Comment: I had to use `mysql_native_password` instead of `caching_sha2_password`  for this to work: 

`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'yourpasswd';`. Not sure why, though.

Comment: @dvlcube this work for me in Mysql 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4

Comment: I had trouble with the order of the commands but in ubuntu 20 worked for me: `sudo service mysql stop` `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &` then opening mysql console with `mysql -u root` `UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=null WHERE User='root'; flush_privileges; ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'yourpasswd'; exit;` `ps -fea | grep mysqld` `sudo kill -9 [pid from previous command]` then finally `sudo service mysql stop`

Comment: @Jack Chern What a great person you are, I spent a day solving this problem and there is no article I haven't read. I reset the server many times with no results. Thank you so much.

Comment: God bless you! Finally, I changed the root password.

Comment: This gives me the same syntax error that the OP has

Answer (score 81):

Jus login to MySQL with `sudo`:

```
sudo mysql
```

Then:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'yourpasswd';
exit;
```

Test it:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: thats worked like a charm ! thank you and i dont needed to flush or restart

Comment: Please note, that using this password algo breaks Java applications with the error "public key retrieval is not allowed"

It's better to use the good ol' native password algo 

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your_password; or you may be forced to change the application settings

Comment: Lot of confusing answers elsewhere. This is the one works best.

Comment: I wasted so much time following the actual official MySQL 8 instructions and this is what worked... Thanks

Comment: saved a lot of my time!

Comment: this must be the accepted answer

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: sudo mysql solves nothing in my case: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: I cannot believe how long I wasted on other answers, including the useless mysql documentation and reinstalling my system and all I needed to do was type sudo mysql.

Comment: Simple & working solution so far for mysql version 8*

Comment: This did not work for me. I got the exact same permissions error as the OP when I tried.

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```sql
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'newPasswd';
```

Comment: This statement is not available before adding skip-grant-tables and after that user gets: ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement

Answer (score 6):

*If you are on Windows you can try following steps.*

### Reset MySQL 8.0 root Password in Windows

1. Stop the `MySQL 8.0` service from services.
2. Go to path `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin` and open `cmd`.
3. Run `mysqld --console --skip-grant-tables --shared-memory`.
4. Open new `cmd` in the same path.
5. Run following commands.
6. `mysql -u root`.
7. `select authentication_string,host from mysql.user where user='root';`
8. `UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string='' WHERE user='root';`
9. Now close both the `cmd`.
10. Restart the MySQL 8.0 service.
11. Connect using username as `root` and password as blank.
12. Change the password from the user management.

Found this at: https://gist.github.com/pishangujeniya/0f839d11a7e692dadc49821c274a2394

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new file in your root directory( e.g C:)
2. Write this `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'abc'` and save it
3. If your Mysql service is already running, please stop this and open your CMD
4. Go to your Mysql installation directory (e.g `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin`) and type this command

   ```
   mysql --init-file=C:/init.sql
   ```
5. Execute this command and you are good to go

Refer this video for more clarification : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LsdV-7dFOhk

Answer (score 1):

I am using 8.0.23 but had multiple issues. Here are the issues and solutions.
I followed the mysql docs and was able to do the reset, though I had isues. I have provided my solutions and a sample reset script.

Issues

1. following steps outlined by others had various failures
2. user running daemon is mysql and I cannot su to mysql id
3. getting error can't create lock file /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock.lock , mysqld folder is getting deleted by the mysql service.
4. had to kill -9 mysql process after running, very ugly

Solutions

1. use steps from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html
2. use --user=mysql when running mysql commands
3. Create folder /var/run/mysqld and chown for mysql:mysql before runing comamnds
4. use mysqladmin shutdown to stop sql after starting it for reset

In the script, I will reset root to New%Password

```
# create password reset file
cat << EOF >/tmp/deleteme
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'New%Password';
EOF
# create /var/run/mysqld
mkdir /var/run/mysqld
chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
# start mysqld and run the command
mysqld --init-file=/tmp/deleteme --user=mysql &
# wait for sql to start
while [ ! -f /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock.lock ]; do sleep 1; done
sleep 3
# stop sql
mysqladmin -u root -pNew%Password shutdown
while [ -f /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock.lock ]; do sleep 1; done
#clean up temp file
rm /tmp/deleteme
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for MySQL Ver 8.0.34-0 on Ubuntu 22.04

```bash
mysql --version
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld
sudo chown mysql /var/run/mysqld/
sudo mysqld_safe  --skip-grant-tables &
```

You need to enter after few lines display in skip grant table command

```bash
sudo mysql --user=root mysql
mysql>exit
mysql -u root -p
```

Answer (score -7):

Using SQLYog you can execute commands

- User Creation

  ```sql
  CREATE USER 'tester'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Pass123#d'
  ```
- Authorization

  ```sql
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON sakila.* TO 'tester'@'localhost'
  ```
- Changing Password in MySQL 8.0

  ```sql
  ALTER USER 'tester'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Pass123#d';
  ```

  or if u know the authentication_string directly set it to update

  ```sql
  UPDATE mysql.user 
  SET authentication_string='*F9B62579F38BE95639ACB009D79427F2D617158F'  
  WHERE USER='root'
  ```
- Changing password in lower versions of mysql

  ```sql
  GRANT USAGE ON *.\* TO 'tester'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Pass123#d'
  SET PASSWORD FOR 'tester'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('Pass123#d');
  ```

Comment: Can you explain that further? What is "SQLYog"? How does all this work if one cannot login as root?