# MySQL lost root password

Tags: mysql

This seems like a simple question but has caused me endless hours of frustration. It is only a small box inside the house that I am using for playing around.

I've tried the skip-grant-tables version and used the authentication_string field rather than the password version that is still knocking around. I've also tried the init-file method but no joy.

If I use the skip-grant-tables version and use the line:

```
update user set authentication_string=password('whywontitwork') where user='root';
```

The result I get is:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('whywontitwork') where user='root'' at line 1
```

I don't understand (at all) what is wrong with the syntax. It is driving me mad for what should be a tiny little issue (I think). Does anybody have any ideas?  Thanks in advance.
MySQL Ver 8.0.21-0ubuntu running on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: You've  to specify database while querying table, ie use  `mysql.user`

Comment: From the answers to the duplicate question pls follow this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58517061/5389997

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `PASSWORD()` is not working in MySql 8.0. You can use other encryption functions: [LINK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password)

How to reset root password in MySQL > 8.0: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691977/how-to-reset-the-root-password-in-mysql-8-0-11)

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'NewPassword';
```

you can also create mysql-init file and apply this command by file

```
mysqld --init-file=/home/me/mysql-init &
```