# Docker mysql change password

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

My docker-compose look like:

```yaml
version: '3.4'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    command:
      - --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

My .env file look like:

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_DATABASE=db
MYSQL_USER=user
MYSQL_PASSWORD=user
```

Now if I change the password in `.env` file, it does not change the password in the docker container after the restart.
I suppose that happens because I have mapped volume from host to container and I think there are all settings saved.

My question is: How can I change the password for mysql, without modyfing or deleting `mysql-data` folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can log in to the MySQL shell inside the container and then manually change the password following any standard MySQL guide.

To log in to the container, execute `docker exec -it <container-id> mysql -u root -p` and provide the root password when prompted. After logging in, you can follow this guide to change the password: [How to reset the root password in MySQL 8.0.11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691977/how-to-reset-the-root-password-in-mysql-8-0-11)

To log in to the container shell (not MySQL shell), execute `docker exec -it <container-id> bash`.

Comment: I do not remember the password for MySQL root

Comment: It's "root", from your env file

Comment: Yes but is not actual

Comment: So you've lost the env file? In that case, you can do `docker inspect <container-id> | grep MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`. This will give you the password