# Resetting MySql root password in Windows 10

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I haven't used MySQL in a while and forgot my root password.  I initialized a springboot application but I can't seem to connect to my database.  I don't remember my root password.  Is there an easy way to reset the password?  Would it be easier to uninstall MySQL and reinstall it and start from scratch?  I don't need any of the existing databases I currently have stored.

I am just trying to get a springboot application to connect to my database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset the root password in MySQL 8.0.11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691977/how-to-reset-the-root-password-in-mysql-8-0-11)