# spring boot project can not access mysql db that is created by docker

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, privileges, sqlexception

I am developing a Spring boot Project without docker and I try to connect a MYSQL 8 db. I created db by docker. But Spring boot project can not access the mysql. There is an exception that "Access denied for user 'root'@'172.21.0.1' (using password: YES)".

However I can access that by using mysql Workbench and I can access mysql terminal.

I try to solve by running that these commands on mysql terminal:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'127.21.0.1' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

How Can I proceed and solve this problem?

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 020688
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ticketdb
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 020688
      MYSQL_USER: root
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
```

ticket-service.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: ticket-service
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ticketdb
    username: root
    password: 020688
  jpa:
    database: mysql
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
```

Exeption:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'172.21.0.1' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
```

Comment: i'm not sure but do you have a mysql container already running ? Maybe that is the problem. Chek out here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59839180/10909386

Comment: Yes, that is running and I can access that in terminal and mysql workbenc GUI. And Exception is about priviliges. If it is about connection failure to host , maybe it can be about if running or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your SQL GRANT, you've created a user with the host 127.21.0.1, but your app seems to be running on 172.21.0.1

It might be a misstype in the question though.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. I fixed by your comment and it works

Comment: Hi, you should mark that issue by solved. The right answer was phaen's answer, this mistype was made afterwards I think

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to connect as the root user from another host I assume (as this is what it looks like). Per default, mysql does not allow this (afaik).

Maybe have a look at this post, might be solving your issue:

[mysql-root-access-from-all-hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223235/mysql-root-access-from-all-hosts)

Comment: Hi, I readed that post and  I added a new user 'root'@'172.21.0.1' with all priviliges.
And 'root@'%' with all priviliges had existed. Again there is a same error