# not able to connect mysql from sequel or terminal

Tags: mysql, docker, sequelpro

I'm using mysql in docker. I can access docker through docker exec terminal. But I can't access it outside through my regular terminal or sequel ace.

What I'm getting in in sequel ace and in regular terminal

**Access denied**

Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 because access was denied.

Double-check your username and password and ensure that access from your current location is permitted.

MySQL said: Access denied for user 'crowdtank'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Access denied for user 'crowdtank'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Terminal command and output for access attempt
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'crowdtank'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

My docker code

```
version: '3'

networks:
  laravel:

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
     - laravel

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: crowdtank
      MYSQL_USER: crowdtank
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: crowdtank
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: crowdtank
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - laravel
```

Comment: Did you edit the password at any point? Clean out `./mysql` folder and try again

Comment: Alternatively, add another container for phpmyadmin

Comment: please, share commands you use to connect to dockerized mysql

Comment: THis is my command for try to access the sql
crowdtank % mysql -u crowdtank -p

And output is 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'crowdtank'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: You most probably started your mysql container against a preexisting mysql data filesystem. If this is the case, restart on a fresh empty db data filesystem. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838692/mysql-root-password-is-set-but-getting-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost/59839180#59839180

Comment: I tried this command 
docker-compose down -v
docker-compose up -d
but not working

Comment: Does it work with `docker exec -it mysql mysql -u crowdtank -p crowdtank`?

Comment: yes its work. I think there's something I'm missing or some configuration needed.

Comment: I think Zeitounator is right and you have a mysqld running on the host. You could check it with `netstat -tulpen | grep 3306` and then try it again after stopping the service.

Comment: how to check this in mac?