# Can't connect to MariaDB running on Docker, getting 1045 error

Tags: database, docker, mariadb

I am trying to run a MariaDB database over docker. I've started the container with the following command:

```
docker run -p 3306:3306 --detach --name mymariadb --env MARIADB_USER=admin --env MARIADB_PASSWORD=admin --env MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root  mariadb:latest
```

I know have a C#-Skript that should connect to MariaDB and create a database. I know the skript works, because it has worked for other people in my class and for me as well in the past for other databases.
I have the following connection string:

```
Server=localhost;User ID=admin;Password=admin;
```

When I run the skript I get an error 1045:Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost'.

Does anyone know what could be the problem or even how I could troubleshoot?

I've tried restarting the container and replacing the user name and password, but it didn't work.
Then I've tried using Postgres instead (with a different connection string), but it denied access as well, so maybe it has something to do with my firewall?

Comment: Please, review this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838692/mysql-root-password-is-set-but-getting-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost