# MySQL from docker image won't start database

Tags: mysql, docker

I have following service in my docker-compose.yaml:

```
  db:
    image: "mysql:8.0.33"
    container_name: mywebsite-sql
    volumes:
      - .docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql/
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
```

When I run docker compose, mysql container is up and running, but mysql service inside has not started, from container logs:

```
2023-11-26 23:22:45+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.33-1.el8 started.
2023-11-26 23:22:46+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
```

When I try to execute mysql command inside container:

```
sh-4.4# mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

When I try to run mysqld by hand inside container, I'm getting following error:

```
sh-4.4# mysqld
2023-12-05T23:11:02.618578Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2023-12-05T23:11:02.626541Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33) starting as process 61
2023-12-05T23:11:02.631689Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
2023-12-05T23:11:02.667038Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011011] [Server] Failed to find valid data directory.
2023-12-05T23:11:02.667419Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-12-05T23:11:02.667481Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-12-05T23:11:02.669140Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Data directory seems to be a problem - how can I fix it? I'm on MacOS Ventura 13.4 OS.

Edit: I can't even simply run container based on mysql images without any volumes, command "docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:latest" from official mysql docker docs gives same result as described in question. I'm trying run it on Apple M2

Comment: Does the `.docker/mysql` directory exist? What permissions does it have?

Comment: Can you try connecting from a separate container; `docker-compose run db mysql -hdb`?  If you set `ports:` on the container, you can `brew install` or similar a MySQL client on the host and access it without doing anything Docker-specific.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MYSQL\_ROOT\_PASSWORD is set but getting "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" in docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838692/mysql-root-password-is-set-but-getting-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

Comment: @KKI no, this is not the case - mysql service inside container has not even started. In question I've posted complete logs from container, there are just above two lines

Comment: I can't even simply run container based on mysql images without any volumes, command "docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:latest" from official mysql docker docs gives same result as described in question.

Comment: In your docker configuration, is your volume directory is specified within the resources section? For example with Docker Desktop on Mac, under Settings->Resources->File Sharing. If it is not, Docker will not mount the volume.