# Access denied for user 'PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT_TEAM'@'172.18.0.1' (using password: YES) on Docker

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I've been looking for some solutions so far but the existing ones are not able to solve my current predicament on connecting MySQL database instance from Docker.

Here's my code on the Docker Compose file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
 mysql:
  image: mysql:8.0
  container_name: mysql8.0
  restart: always
  environment:
   - MYSQL_DATABASE="PROFILEDEV"
   - MYSQL_USER="PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT_TEAM"
   - MYSQL_PASSWORD="PROFILE$32DEVINSTANCE"
   - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="PROFILE$32DEVINSTANCE"
  ports:
  - "3306:3306"
  expose:
  - "3306"
  volumes:
  - mysql-db:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
   mysql-db:
```

I've tried to spin it up and it has created the database. But to connect it, it throws an error saying
*Access denied for user 'PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT_TEAM'@'172.18.0.1' (using password: YES)*

Any solution to this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Syntactically, I'd ask whether the quotes in the environment variables are causing problems (is the created user named literally `"PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT_TEAM"`, including the quotes as part of the name?) and whether the `$` in the passwords are being interpreted as an environment variable expansion (does `$$` work better?).

Comment: I've removed the quotes part and the `$` part as well and I'm still facing the same issue

Comment: Try running it without the volume. From the docs: "Do note that none of the [environment] variables below will have any effect if you start the container with a data directory that already contains a database: any pre-existing database will always be left untouched on container startup."

Comment: Removing without the volume would produce this error `service "mysql" refers to undefined volume mysql-db: invalid compose project`.

Comment: The error message means that you have provided the incorrect user name and/or password when you tried to login to mysql. You need to review the user access rights and passwords in mysql and make sure you use the correct one in your client. There is not much else we can say about this error. Please do not say that your user names and passwords are correct as mysql tells us otherwise and I trust mysql over your claim. Sorry.

Comment: Probably your comment didn't help as I did enter the same username and password countless and it fails to authenticate. I drives me nuts when you provide the same credentials and then you trust mysql claim.

Comment: Is your mysql user allowed to connect from the IP address specified in the access denied error message?

Comment: @Shadow Closing the question and linking to a similar question that doesn't have an accepted answer feels unhelpful to me

Comment: I got to solve the issue. Had reformat my YAML file, run this command `docker compose -f mysql-docker-compose.yaml down -v` to delete the instance from Docker with the persistant file and compose back up again running this command `docker compose -f mysql-docker-compose.yaml up -d. Now I'm able to login again. Something was wrong with the YAML file. The question that you linked @HansKilian did not help at all. This did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838692/mysql-root-password-is-set-but-getting-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost

Comment: Your `down -v` deleted the volume. I'm pretty sure you had an existing database in the volume with a different username/password defined. Deleting the volume fixed it, since the next start of the container created the database and user from scratch.

Comment: Exactly @HansKilian. It wasn't deleting the volume properly I guess. Thanks anyways